# Using of set_time_limit (0);

Tags: php, sockets

I want to ask,if we are using

```
 set_time_limit (0);
```

In implementing socket,does this will not consume memory ? because our server will run everyday without shutting down and my socket listener keeps listening or receiving data everyday.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: research php daemons

Comment: I searched it and many results found, have you tried using this php daemons,and which one did you try,thank you in advance.